# Arguments of function main() in searching files

Tags: c, variables, search, program-entry-point

I write some code which should search string of characters in the given text files. When no argument is given you receive information it return an information that you shoul give at least one argument. If you give to program only one argument which is string of character to find you have to write how many filest do you want to search. Next step is to give path for those files. The problem is when you write more than one. The last path is only searched. The first loop indicated that paths are assigned well but printf after the loop show that sometning went wrong. What I should change at this code?
Code added below.
For any help thank's a lot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc==1){
        printf("No arguments given"); 
        return -1;   
    }else if(argc==2){
        int i=1,path_quantity=0;
        while(path_quantity==0){
        printf("How many path will you given:\n");
        scanf("%d",&path_quantity);
        }
        char path[30];
        int c;
        for(i;i<=path_quantity;i++){
            printf("Give path numver %d:\n",i);
            scanf("%30s",wyraz);
            fflush(stdin);
            argv[1+i]=path;
            printf("%s\n",argv[1+i]);

        }
        printf("0: %s 1: %s 2: %s 3: %s 4: %s\n",argv[0],argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],argv[4]);

        int j;
        for (j=2; j<path_quantity+2; j++){
        FILE *f= fopen(argv[j], "r");
        if(!f) {
            perror("Can't open file\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t nread;
        while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
            char *occur = strstr(line, argv[1]);
            if(occur != 0){         
                printf("%s", line);
            }
        }
        fclose(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while(path_quantity==0){ printf("How many path will you given:\n"); scanf("%d",&path_quantity); }
Why this while loop it will cause infinite loop

Comment: This piecie of code do not cause infinite loop. It only requires to give a number which is different than 0.In the body of that loop you assign a number to this variable.So if you give anything which is different than 0 the code is done to it's end.

Comment: If every time user enter 0 it will be infinite

Comment: You are right but we don't consider this case.The problem is that doesn't really matter how many you give path to files of course without 0.The program will given you as a result last file search multiply for number of path you have given. It is probably related with assign further paths to argv[].

Answer (score -1):

You should not change content or argv argv is a constent array of pointer.

Comment: So how  I should  keep those paths at memory?In Js it will be no problem the solution will be a table with few string elements but in C is problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i;i<=path_quantity;i++){ printf("Give path numver %d:\n",i); scanf("%30s",wyraz); fflush(stdin); argv[1+i]=path; printf("%s\n",argv[1+i]); }
```

Instead of using argv you should use array of pointer implementaion through malloc.please read about dynamic array of pointer implementaion that will solve your problem.